# Split 1 Loop Into 2 Column in PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach

I made tables using foreach loop, it looks like this

[image]

How do i split it into two column like this:

[image]

Comment: can you please show us your loop code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to conditionally split your elements into two different groups:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<div class='left'>$i</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='right'>$i</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

And then use CSS to [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) the columns next to each other:

```
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Print it out simply in PHP:

```
<div class="grid">
<?php
    foreach($tables as $table){
        echo "<div>".$table."</div>";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Yields:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>Table Code</div>
    <div>Table Code</div>
    <div>Table Code</div>
    <div>Table Code</div>
</div>
```

Then style with CSS Grid:

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid > div{
    border: blue 3px dashed;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>Table Code</div>
    <div>Table Code</div>
    <div>Table Code</div>
    <div>Table Code</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `for` loop, increasing by 2. This also reduce the number of iteration.

**PHP**

```
$arr = range(1, 10);
echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$arr[$i]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$arr[$i + 1]}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```